# what's meaning %type on the Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure(Oracle 11g) and inside the Procedure I have this line.

```
v_prazo_subs_ans         ts_odo.odo_controle_sistema.val_parametro%type;
```

Where I have:

My variable: `v_prazo_subs_ans`

My table: `ts_odo.odo_controle_sistema`

The field of my table: `val_parametro`

What does `%type` after the name of the field mean?

Answer (score 4):

> %TYPE
>
> Represents the datatype of a previously declared collection, cursor
>   variable, field, object, record, database column, or variable.

in other words instead of using `VARCHAR2`, `NUMBER`, etc... you can just say `the parameter of my procedure has same type as a column`. this is really useful when you need change type of column in your table, you don't need make any changes in your pl/sql code

see docs here:

[Constant and Variable Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/constantvar_declaration.htm#i33299)

[Procedure Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/procedure_declaration.htm)